# How to override Bootstrap theme colors in bootstrapped react/redux app?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, bootstrap-4

probably a newbie questions (starting with REACT) but I am unable to change the theme colors in my newly bootstrapped react application.

I read some answers but unfortunately, they did not work for me.

I have the following entry point:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './components/App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import './styles/app.scss';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and I have `app.scss` style sheet in `src/styles`:

```
@import '_settings.scss';
@import '_base.scss';
@import './components/_header.scss';
```

I tried changing the theme colors here but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #991196,
  "danger": #ff4136
);
```

Could someone point out to me how this works since all the answers and tuturials I came across seem to be using different approaches.

I am using the following version of Bootstrap:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0"
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First refer this, [Bootstrap webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/webpack/)

This is one way of using bootstrap in reactjs projects.

You are importing compiled version of bootstrap css by doing this

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; //Dont do this
```

Instead you should do this

In your *app.scss* file,

first define your color

```
$primary: #13C7CD;
$danger: #red;
```

then

import scss version of bootstrap

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

---

`~` means webpack will search for it in `node_modules`

After this import the app.scss file in your main js file(can be index.js or app.js)

```
import './styles/app.scss';
```

**How this works**

When you define your color variables before importing bootstrap scss, the
resulting complied css will have your color values

For Vite users, add the following in `vite.config.js`

```
const path = require('path')

export default {
  root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    hot: true
  }
}
```

Then in SCSS file

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My mistake was importing the Bootstrap before re-defining the colors. But your explanation makes sense so I will use it this way.

Comment: If using Vite? how to import bootstrp/scss/bootstrap

Comment: @sgClaudia98 refer this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/vite/#import-bootstrap

Answer (score 8):

You can make the overrides and import Bootstrap entirely in the `app.scss` file. It's important the Bootstrap is imported *after* the theme color changes to override the !default theme-colors defined in bootstrap _variables.scss.

```
    @import '_settings.scss';
    @import '_base.scss';
    @import './components/_header.scss';

    /* import only the Bootstrap files needed for customizations */
    @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
    @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

    /* make the customizations */
    $theme-colors: (
      "primary": #991196,
      "danger": #ff4136
    );

    /* import bootstrap to set changes */
    @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss";
```

When the react app is built and the SASS is compiled then generated CSS will contain your customizations and Bootstrap so that you won't need to separately import bootstrap in react.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/Tho2TEwoI1

Answer (score 1):

[image]The simplest way...

Just import/define YOUR styles before BOOTSTRAP styles. That's it! 'Happy hacking'